# CSQuery select elements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, csquery

I have an html file as following:

```
<h3>
    <div id='type'>
        Type 1
    </div>

    <div id='price'>
        127.76;
    </div>
</h3>

 <h3>
    <div id='type'>
        Type 2
    </div>

    <div id='price'>
        127.76;
    </div>
</h3>
```

Now I want to use CSQuery to extract those types and price into a List, here is the code I'm working on :

var doc = CQ.Create(htmlfile);

```
var types= (from listR in doc["<h3>"] //get the h3 tag
    select new TypeTest
    {
        Typename =  listR.GetAttribute("#type"),
        Price = listR.GetAttribute("#price")
    }
    ).ToList();
return types;
```

However, I couldn't get the details as I wish, as I'm not sure about the doc[] value when I put it as h3. the html file cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html that you are parsing is an invalid format i.e. multiple identical id's. (There are two `id='type'` and `id='price`), you must take the following steps.

1. Load the dom
2. Load the collections of type and price divs separately.
3. Use the Zip function to join them back together and project into you `TypeTest` object.

Below is a working example:

```
// 1
var doc = CQ.Create(html);

// 2
var typeDivs = doc["h3 > div#type"];
var priceDivs = doc["h3 > div#price"];

// 3
var types = typeDivs.Zip(priceDivs, (k, v) => new { k, v })
     .Select(h => 
      new TypeTest { Typename = h.k.InnerText.Trim(), 
      Price = h.v.InnerText.Trim() });
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me again, I tried both cases but then it still doesn't work, I'm still quite new to this type of parsing @hutchonoid

Comment: @bluewonder No problem, there you go. A full working example. :)

Comment: @bluewonder Hi, I don't unfortunately. Might be worth asking another question, someone will be able to answer it I'm sure.